# table column width in datalist

Tags: asp.net, datalist

How can I adjust the column width of a table inside a datalist ? I have tried applying the width through CSS and directly on the tag but it doesn't affect the table
 [image]

```
 <asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource2" Height="409px" RepeatColumns="3" Width="600px" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table class="nav-justified"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
            <tr>
                <td><asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("productImage") %>'  Width="120" Height="60" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="width:120px">
                <td> <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" CssClass="productName"  NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("product.aspx?id={0}", Eval("productId")) %>'>HyperLink</asp:HyperLink> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="width:120px">
                 <td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" class="productPrice" Text='<%# Eval("productPrice") %>' ></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="width:120px">
                <td> <asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="addToCart" runat="server" Text="+" />  </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
   </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: You must set the width of the `td` elements, not that of the `tr` elements.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I tried that but still its the same

Comment: I assume that the image in the question is the current resulting layout. Can you show an image with the layout that you want?

Comment: @ConnorsFan Thanks for your help . I fixed it by changing the datalist width to 500px

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the Datalist width property. Changing it 400 made the columns to be closer

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource2" Height="409px" RepeatColumns="3" Width="400px" >
<ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: This is an attempt at a self-answer.  It could be improved by including more information.

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others